# IMEI.info knows my phone before I put sim

Tags: android, websites

Recently I brought a Moto G3 turbo phone, which I suspect is a factory reset by a seller from other customer, and dispatched to me.

I search net for getting in if its factory reset, but non tricks worked, 
eg: ##786#, *#*#786#8#* for getting refurbished information as mentioned in [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/21101/how-to-tell-if-your-phone-is-refurbished)

I want to know, how does [www.IMEI.info](http://imei.info) knows my IMEI number even though I have not put any sim in phone yet, I must add I am connected to wifi.

So how does [www.IMEI.info](http://imei.info) works, or is my phone used previously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the [IMEI article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Mobile_Station_Equipment_Identity#Structure_of_the_IMEI_and_IMEISV_.28IMEI_Software_Version.29) and you will find out that the IMEI:

> ... includes information on the origin, model, and serial number of the device.

So no there is magic there and it has nothing to do if the device is resold are not, because the information are all contained in the IMEI itself. The IMEI is generated by the manufacturer  of the device and relates to the hardware. It does not depend on registering the device, carrier, selling, phone number, SIM card or similar.

Answer (score 1):

All these IMEI information provider website services do is simply analyse the number. They don't have to run the number across any database or something. Certain parts of the number give certain information about it like the manufacturer, color, phone model. It's like a phone number actually.

PS for OP: Far as I understand you are somehow worried that just because that number is recorded on the database your phone is used earlier. You shouldn't be. They aren't related at all.